# Getting error in Azure Stream Analytics with DocumentDB as sink

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I'm using Azure Stream Analytics to stream events from Event Hubs to DocumentDB.
I have configured the *input*, *query* and *output* as documented, tested it with sample data and it managed to return results as expected.

But when I start the streaming job and send the same payload as the sample data earlier, I got this error message:

> There was a problem formatting the document [id] column as per DocumentDB constraints for DocumentDB db:[my-database-name], and collection:[my-collection-name].

My sample data is an array of JSON:

```
[
 { "Sequence": 1, "Tenant": "T1", "Status": "Started" },
 { "Sequence": 2, "Tenant": "T1", "Status": "Ended" }
]
```

I've configured the input as follows:

> - Input alias: eventhubs-events
> - Source Type: Data stream
> - Source: Event Hub
> - Subscription: *same subscription as where I create the Analytics job*
> - Service bus namespace: *an existing Event Hub namespace*
> - Event hub name: events *(existing event hub in the namespace)*
> - Event hub policy name: *a policy with read access*
> - Event hub consumer group: *blank*
> - Event serialization format: JSON
> - Encoding: UTF-8

And the output as follows:

> - Output alias: documentdb-events
> - Sink: DocumentDB
> - Subscription: *same subscription as where I create the Analytics job*
> - Account id: *an existing DocumentDB account*
> - Database: records *(an existing database in the account)*
> - Collection name pattern: collection *(an existing collection in the database)*
> - Document id: id

My query is as simple as:

```
SELECT
    event.Sequence AS id,
    event.Tenant,
    event.Status
INTO [documentdb-events]
FROM [eventhubs-events] AS event
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out all field names in the output are automatically lower-cased.

In my DocumentDB collection, I've configured the collections in **Partitioned** mode, with **"/Tenant"** as the Partition Key.

Since the case didn't match that of the output, it failed the constraint.

Changing the Partition Key to "/tenant" fixed the issue.

Hope by sharing the outcome of my findings could save some trouble for people who bump into this.

**2nd Option**

Instead of changing partition key in lower case, now we can change [compatibility-Level](http://stream-analytics-compatibility-level) in Stream analytics.

> 1.0 versions: Field names were changed to lower case when processed by the Azure Stream Analytics engine.
>
> 1.1 version: case-sensitivity is persisted for field names when they are processed by the Azure Stream Analytics engine.