# Not working - Azure Stream Analytics with Blob OR Event as input and DocumentDB as Output Sink

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

Using Azure Stream Analytics to stream events from Blob OR Event Hubs to DocumentDB. Configuration has been done as per Microsoft documentation, "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-get-started"

When I am trying to give input as Event Hubs OR Blob in stream analytics and output sink as documentdb, Then I am not able to see any json data in document explorer.

In the Stream Analytics Query, I uploaded a JSON File, and I am getting Output in a single line. I followed some links [Azure Stream Analytics is not feeding DocumentDB output sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168652/azure-stream-analytics-is-not-feeding-documentdb-output-sink) and [Getting error in Azure Stream Analytics with DocumentDB as sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502231/getting-error-in-azure-stream-analytics-with-documentdb-as-sink)

But not able to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing to a partitioned documentdb? If so, try providing criteria to filter on your partition key. I had a few collections that wouldn't show me documents in document explorer unless I provided criteria, even though I could return documents via query explorer.

Edit: You can provide this criteria by adding a filter.

Click the filter button:

[image]

Add filter criteria that includes whatever field you use for partition key. In my case I use deviceID, so my filter is `c.deviceID = "SomeDeviceIDThatIWantToFind"`:[image]

Comment: Yes writing to a partitioned doc db, But can you please help me on how to provide partition key using Column Name Pattern, because "partition key" is shown as optional. "https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs.md"

Comment: I have not observed this behavior in newer DocumentDB instances. In older instances where the behavior is observed, I can reliably reproduce the issue by omitting filter criteria.

I can't speak to why this is required for certain older instances. That's a question for the product team. Presumably it's to limit cost incurred from cross-partition queries.

Comment: Sorry.. actually not using Partitioned document db, I just re looked, I am using 10 GB instance, and partition key here is taken automatically.

Comment: Are you able to return documents via query explorer instead of document explorer?

Comment: Nope cant able to return.